# Multivariable Calculus Change of Variable in Double Integral 2D Jacobian

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $D$ be the region in the first quadrant ($x>0$, $y>0$) of the $xy$-plane bounded by the curves

- $y=\sqrt x$,
- $y=2\sqrt x$,
- $x^2+y^2=1$,
- $x^2+y^2=4$.

Using a change of variables, evaluate the double integral
$$\int\int_D\frac{2x^2+y^2}{xy} dA.$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all , it is clear that u will have to set your u and v  in this form :

u = $y/{\sqrt x}$ , v = $x^2 + y^2 $
(Could also consider using u= $y^2 / x $ instead for easier computation but remember to change your values accordingly)

Next , the conventional way is to compute x and y directly in terms of u and v but in this case, it would be too troublesome to do so. Hence, we make use of the fact that det(A) = $\frac{1}{det(B)}$ to calculate the absolute value of the Jacobian instead. It would be just simple integration after that.